# Windows Forms is Blurred and zoomed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed Windows Forms application on Visual Studio 2022 .Net 4.7 version.
I have included app.manifest to my application and enabled or uncomment the following, and set AutoScaleMode to Font to Main Form property. I have tried all modes but the issue still persists.

```
<!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

 <!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
       DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
       to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
       also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. 
       
       Makes the application long-path aware. See https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation -->


  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

**The Problem**

The application looks fine and clear at a high resolution on the pc it is developed. But, When I am creating a setup by adding a new Setup project to visual studio and installing this app on a different pc it gets blurred and zooms in also the application gets bigger.

I want to know that, do I have to include the app.manifest into the setup file if so. how is it done?

**Desired Behavior**

I want my application to look the same on all windows 10 pc

Comment: Make sure the you have selected the manifest in the dropdown in Application tab of your project properties.

Comment: In the resources section of my project properties in Application "icon and manifest" is already selected.

Comment: Test .Net Framework 4.8 and add DpiAware settings in `App.config` (`PerMonitorV2`). Note that DpiAware settings in `App.manifest` override what's in `App.settings`

Comment: I have also tried this 
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection><add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>

Comment: Still the application gets blurred when i install this on different computer